# HTML5 local storage and impact/load on browsers

Tags: html, browser, local-storage

I had a doubt regarding HTML5 storage technologies like WebSQL, WebStorage/LocalStorage, and indexedDB and to a lesser extent appCache.

Considering the case of chrome (my default browser), these stores are maintained in chrome browser's own directory. Do they impact the starting-up time of the browser?
A colleague has said to experience browser slowing down or behaving in sluggish manner when a larger amount of data is stored.

Couldn't find references to how these technologies impact the browser working, so would love if any fellow-stacker could guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be careful : the WebSQL API is dead (it was based on sqlite instead of a generic API and so was judged not desirable by the Mozilla team, the [Indexed Database API](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indexed_Database_API) will be used instead but you should probably wait for it to be more supported).

LocalStorage is fine, I use it in all my web applications without problems nor measurable boot time. But keep it for parameters, preferences, and so on, as the only reliable storage is always server side. The local storage can be removed, lost, modified, not readable for many reasons (user uses another browser or computer for example). And it seems to me that a big local storage is a burden to the user and thus not very correct (which is probably the reason why this size is limited).

BTW, there is no reason a reasonnable local storage could slow in a measurable manner the launching of a browser.

Comment: Thanks. I tried understanding the migration from WebSQL to IndexedDB Api using [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webdatabase/websql-indexeddb/) but couldn't understand. Feels pretty hard. Also in the ['live example'](http://ido-green.appspot.com/WebSQL-IndexedDB-example/main.html), the indexedDB part doesn't seem to work. The webSQL part works just fine though............... And on why storage may slow down browser, my thought were on chrome having to load all of those on boot. Good if it doesn't!

Comment: Personally I'm not so enthusiastic about complex local storage (for the reasons mentioned in my answer). I would recommend to refrain using that and prefer a server side solution if you can manage a server. users usually have many browsers/computers and don't expect to lose their web app data when they erase their browser data. The browser is not (yet) an OS.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with dystroy; Normally the local storing is harmless if done the right way. Storing **MASSIVE** amounts of data in the browser on the other hand is quite discouraged. It won't slow down the browser performance overall but will slow down the web app using it (as far as I know, Chrome fetches the local storage values dynamically when the 'owner app' is called).

Comment: `[citation/references needed]`